# FTP to remote server

Tags: android, ftp, port, ftp-client, forwarding

My problem is the following I want to develop and app that downloads some files in a ftp server(my laptop) which I could easily solve if I were on the same lan.

What can I do to connect by ftp to my laptop when the phone is connected to a different lan than the computer?

Can be this problem solved by setting my router to port forward? How can I do this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm assuming you address the FTP server as a local IP address, this indeed bind your setup to your current LAN.
What you can do to access it from anywhere is the following:

1. set up an account at no-ip.biz (free) - that will give you a static name bound to your external IP. You can use that name to access your computer from anywhere thats connected to the internet
2. set up port forwarding in your router - this is a specific process for each router but the general idea is to teach your router to forward requests on a specific port (in your case 21) to a specific computer (in your case the laptop).

Once you do these two things it's just a matter of changing your connection target from the LAN ip to your dedicated .no-ip.biz address!

Comment: Thanks, but I was wondering of there was any way that I could just type ftp whatever on a terminal and access my computer or if port forwarding. Anyway your help is very useful

Comment: Nevertheless, it was very useful for the app. Thank you a lot